# Decir si una serie de números es positiva o no

Tags: c

Buenos días.

Quisiera saber por qué no me funciona correctamente éste pequeño programita. Llevo casi 1 hora intentando encontrar el error, pero no hay manera. El programa me compila y se me ejecuta pero a la hora de introducir por ejemplo: 1 2 3 0, me dice que hay almenos un número negativo.

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
        int main (void) {
            int n, cont, cont1, cont2;

            printf ("Escribe una serie de números acabada en 0: "); 
            scanf ("%d", &n);

            cont = 0;

            while ((n != 0) && (n > 0)){
                if (n > 0) {
                    cont1 ++;
                }
                else {
                    cont2 ++;
                }
                scanf ("%d", &n);
                cont ++;
            }       

            if (cont == cont1){
                    printf ("Ésta es una serie positiva.\n");
                }

            else {
                printf ("Hay almenos un número negativo. Vuelve a introducir la serie.\n");
            }

            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Primer de todo, gracias por responder.

Mi intención era hacer que "cont" contara todos los números de la serie, y luego comparar: Si todos los números de la serie positivos == cont, quiere decir que la serie es positiva.

"Y ¿no te parece que esta condición podría simplificarse un poco: (n != 0) && (n > 0)" no se me ocurre nada más simplificable la verdad.

Comment: Eso de dejar las variables sin inicializar ... ¿ Es por algún motivo que se me escapa ? No se, porque busques comenzar con valores aleatorios que den resultados imprevisibles o algo así ;-)

Comment: Joder jaja, se me había escapado xD. Gracias tío ya funciona!

Comment: Es una buena práctica inicializar los contadores a cero al mismo tiempo que han sido declarados: `cont = 0, cont1 = 0, cont2 = 0;`.

Comment: @Trauma ¿y la respuesta donde está? si no la publicas dificilmente la pregunta va a aparecer como solucionada...

Comment: @eferion Casi se puede cerrar como `error tipográfico`. Si lo dices por no entrar en temas ya resueltos ... pues si, tienes razón. Pero es que es tan ... tan ...

Comment: @Trauma lo se... es por darle carpetazo... o se le pone respuesta o se vota para cerrarlo

Comment: @eferion Ahora mismo no puedo ... ¿ borro los comentarios y la escribes ? +1 de mi parte ya tienes :-)

Comment: @Trauma no hay prisa... cuando tengas un rato elaboras la respuesta... no te va a llevar más de 2 minutos :)

Answer (score 0):

En C debes darle un valor inicial a todas las variables locales antes de usarlas (como las variables `n`, `cont`, `cont1`, `cont2` dentro de tu método `main`), de lo contrario tendrán un valor indeterminado y cualquier operación realizada con estas variables tendrá un comportamiento indefinido

En tu código inicializas sólo la variable `n` al valor dado por el usuario y `cont` a 0, pero olvidas darle un valor a las variables `cont1` y `cont2`. Modifica esta línea de código

```
    int n, cont, cont1, cont2;
```

por

```
    int n, cont, cont1 = 0, cont2 = 0;
```